# How can I control the number of non zero weights during training in Keras?

Tags: keras

How can I control the number of non zero weights during optimization and training, such that we have a fixed number `N` of non-zero weights? Something like orthogonal matching pursuit. This could be done by adding the constraint to cost function.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to control weights of a model by using of [regulizers](https://keras.io/regularizers/) in Keras. It works by adding a penalty to a the loss function depending on weights. I used it for sparse autoencoder in a way, like it described in the documentation:

```
from keras import backend as K

def l1_reg(weight_matrix):
    return 0.01 * K.sum(K.abs(weight_matrix))

model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,
                kernel_regularizer=l1_reg)
```

However, it's possible to limit not only sum of weights, but also count of zero weights.  For example, a limit can be `M = weight_matrix.size - N` and penalty depends on an absolute value of a delta between `M` and number of zero weights, so network with the closest number of `non-zero weights` to `N` will have minimal penalty

*Additional info*

From my experience in a process of training weights became equal to zero very rarely, mainly they stay in very small but still non zero value. In this state they're almost have no influence in work of network, so I suggest taking them into account like zero weight by using threshold value

*Code example:*

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from  keras.regularizers import Regularizer

class ZeroWeights(Regularizer):
    def __init__(self, l1=0., N = 0):
        self.l1 = K.cast_to_floatx(l1)
        self.N = int(N)

    def __call__(self, x):
        regularization = 0.
        if self.l1 and self.N:
            regularization += self.l1 * np.abs((self.N - np.count_nonzero(x))) 
        return regularization

    def get_config(self):
        return {'l1': float(self.l1),
                'N': int(self.N)}

model1 = Sequential() 

look_back = 10
dm = 5

model1.add(
    LSTM(64, input_shape = (look_back,dm), W_regularizer=ZeroWeights(0.1, 1331), 
         activation='sigmoid'))
model1.add(Dense(dm)) 
model1.add(Activation("linear")) 
model1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop') 
model1.summary();
```

Comment: Did you mean something like this... def reg1(weight_matrix):
    return 0.01 * (M-len(K.where(weight_matrix==0)))

Comment: @shaifaliGupta: 
Almost, we need positive value for penalty, so it will be like def reg1(weight_matrix): return 0.01 * abs(M-len(K.where(weight_matrix==0))) in pseudocode. It looks like your pseudocode will give reward to network with len(K.where(weight_matrix!=0) > K instead of penalty, but it can make sense if you would like to have network with even less than N non-zero weights. Also, you have to adjust  0.01 constant to your model/data in order to reach optimal results

Comment: class reg_me(Regularizer):
    def __call__(self, x):
        regularization = 0.
        regularization += 0.01 * (102-len(sess.run(K.tf.where(x==0))))
        return regularization                                                                                 I implemented like this..but it gives error InvalidArgumentError: WhereOp : Unhandled input dimensions: 0

Comment: @shaifaliGupta: It's hard to find, out the reason of this error without seeing entire code, could you share it so I can check it?

Comment: class reg_me(Regularizer):
    def __call__(self, x):
        regularization = 0.
        regularization += 0.01 * K.abs((1331-len(sess.run(K.tf.where(x==0)))))
        return regularization

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(64, batch_input_shape=(10,look_back,dm),W_regularizer=reg_me(),activation='sigmoid')) 

model1.add(Dense(dm))
model1.add(Activation("linear"))
model1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')

Comment: @shaifaliGupta: I've added fixed code to my answer, please check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154070/discussion-between-stepan-novikov-and-shaifali-gupta).